# AVAudioSession iOS 12.4.1 Impossible to record audio with Timer.scheduledTimer when the app is in background

Tags: ios, swift, timer, avaudiosession, avaudiorecorder

**Timer works** fine even in the **background** (I can read the logs) but method **AVAudioRecorder.record() doesn't** ... here the scheduled method:

```
@objc func timer(){
        os_log("timer")
        if self.audioRecorder == nil {
            //...some stuff
            self.audioRecorder = try AVAudioRecorder(url: audioFileName, settings: settings)
            self.audioRecorder.delegate = self
            self.audioRecorder.record()
        }
    }
```

the timer settings:

`_ = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 10.0, target: self, selector: #selector(timer), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)`

I have found this issue **after iOS 12.4 update**.

- I use two different instance of **AVAudioSession**
- **It works perfectly** when the app is in **foreground**
- I **play** the audio file tapping it and I **schedule** with **timer** when to **start recorder**
- So i start music, I move the app in **background**, the music **still play**, the **timer fires** ... **BUT** the **recorder doesn't** want to start ..

Maybe a **BUG** ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42319172/swift-3-how-to-make-timer-work-in-background ?

Comment: i have edit the answer to make more readable my issue.

Comment: This looks like a bug https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/120038 Some report that it's fixed in 13.1

Comment: The issue described above has been fixed in iOS 13.1, but it still exists ...