# How can I run a POST request periodically when app is in the background in swift

Tags: swift, asynchronous, swiftui, notifications, background

What i’m after is simple enough to conceptualise, but putting it into practice seems harder than I thought.

I want to trigger a timer to start when a page displaying text results in my app appears. At the given time, (say 60 seconds) it makes a post request, checks the text against the displayed text from the app and notifies the user if there has been any changes.

The user can then choose to update the displayed text or ignore it.

This is a process that id like to happen when the app is in use and also when the app is in the background or ipad is locked.

I have the post request successfully running as an async func called from inside a Task. I am able to run it no problem when the app is active but as soon as the app goes to background, the timer stops.

Id love to give a reproducible example but im using my phone to ask the question, sorry.

Comment: You can't do it on iOS. There are rules about what you can do in the background and this is not one of the things you can do. See https://www.kodeco.com/34269507-background-modes-tutorial-getting-started for a good list.

Comment: You can't use `Timer` when the app is in background, period.

Comment: Background fetch is one of them though. Data refresh. @matt

Comment: this post may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42319172/swift-3-how-to-make-timer-work-in-background